# C# Attribute parameter environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I pass an environment variable to an attribute?

example:

```
[HttpPost(**VARIABLEX**)]
public IActionResult PostCustomer()
{ 

}
```

Comment: When the value of the `VARIABLEX` should be substituted? At the compile time or at the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be specifically in attribute you can achieve this by a bit hackish [custom route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-constraints):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Matches value from "Test" environment variable 
/// </summary>
class EnvRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        IRouter route,
        string routeKey,
        RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var routeValueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (routeValueString is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test")
            ?.Equals(routeValueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false;
    }
}
```

Then in services registration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.ConstraintMap.Add("fromVarTest", typeof(EnvRouteConstraint)));
```

And on controller:

```
[HttpPost("{_:fromVarTest}")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> SomeMethod()
{
}
```